# Select date range on mysql timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying the following but get no results:

```
SELECT *
FROM users_test
WHERE dateadded >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-02-01 00:00:00') 
AND dateadded <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-11-01 00:00:00');
```

Yet I know there are columns with dates within that range e.g.

```
2012-05-11 17:10:08
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Eventually I want to search multiple parameters, albeit not at the same time, like today, yesterday, last week, last month etc and also a date range and month range

Comment: Is your column storing values as a UNIX timestamp or as a timestamp (e.g. `2012-05-11 17:10:08`)?

You pasted an example of a column within that range, but it is not a UNIX timestamp which makes me wonder. You are comparing the dates with a UNIX timestamp, and you might need to just compare with the timestamp.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
SELECT *
FROM users_test
WHERE dateadded >= '2012-02-01 00:00:00'
AND dateadded <  '2012-11-01 00:00:00'
```

For what I can see, it seems your table has the data stored in the same way you want to look for it (`2012-05-11 17:10:08`), so in this case you won't need UNIX_TIMESTAMP.

Also I can see you want to exclude the 2nd date from results (because you're using `<` instead of `<=`), otherwise using `WHERE dateadded BETWEEN '2012-02-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-01 00:00:00'` would be fine as well...

Answer (score 8):

Just use the SQL `BETWEEN` keyword. That's all.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
      users_test
 WHERE
     dateadded BETWEEN '2012-02-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-01 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATE(date_field) between '2015-05-10' and '2015-05-21`
```